# WSL Ubuntu 18.04 Install SSH key forwarding Issue

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I recently updated my WSL Ubuntu install to the 18.04 version available through the Microsoft Store. After the install I ran into issued with the SSH client and the ability to forward keys.

So the issue that I am experiencing is that the ssh-agent would be un-reachable via the ssh client. So I am starting the ssh-agent using `eval ssh-agent -s` command and then adding my keys using `ssh-add`. When I do a `ssh-add -l` the my keys are correctly returned.

Once I connect to my jump host and then try to leverage my forwarded keys on a node, I get a key denied error. When I log off the jump host, and check my keys with my keys using `ssh-add -l` I get an error message stating that there is an error connecting. The pattern keep repeating no what I do. Is there something that I should be looking at to troubleshoot the ssh-agent stability?

Note, I was able to downgrade the install back to the WSL 16.04 build and everything was working again.

Comment: Have you tried [the official WSL Ubuntu 18.04 release](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q)? Make sure to back up your 16.04 stuff first, since [it might destroy it](https://i.imgur.com/MJwvLWW.png).

Comment: Yeah, I tried both the update option and then the official WSL 18.04 version from the microsoft store. ran in to issue ssh-agent issue with both instances.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in openssh client bundled with Ubuntu 18.04 running under WSL in Windows 1803

Please use the following instructions to install [openssh binary from Ubuntu 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/openssh-client/download)

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb
dpkg -x openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb /tmp/deb
sudo mv /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/ssh-agent.18.04
# for safekeeping in case of bionic updates
sudo mv /tmp/deb/usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/ssh-agent.16.04
sudo cp /usr/bin/ssh-agent.16.04 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
sudo chown root:ssh /usr/bin/ssh-agent
```

See more information on this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183)